# Can't enable APR on tomcat

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, jira

Please help. I have jira and I try to install ARP. For this I used the next command :

```
yum install apr.x86_64 apr-devel openssl-devel
```

But I still have error in logs :

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

Can someone help me? thx

P.S. There is my files in /usr/lib64/

```
ls -l /usr/lib64/ | grep apr
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root      18 Jul 31 12:54 apr-1
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       6 Jun  9  2014 apr-util-1
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     944 Jun 10  2014 libapr-1.la
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      17 Jul 31 12:54 libapr-1.so -> libapr-1.so.0.4.8
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      17 Jul 30 12:13 libapr-1.so.0 -> libapr-1.so.0.4.8
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  198600 Jun 10  2014 libapr-1.so.0.4.8
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      21 Jul 30 12:13 libaprutil-1.so.0 -> libaprutil-1.so.0.5.2
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  172288 Jun  9  2014 libaprutil-1.so.0.5.2
```

Comment: have you configured APR in your conf/server.xml?

Comment: If you talking about this line, then yes :)
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="yes"/>